# Facebook Developer Account Change

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

**How can we migrate one facebook account to another?**
Hi everyone! My problem is a little specific because of my company's current scenario.

When the company implemented the facebook login, we were a multi national e-commerce with every country together in the same facebook developer account.

As the years went by, the Brazilian segment split from the rest of the world becoming a company on it's own. Every technology was migrated to brazil (with the database), but the facebook account didn't changed, it's still setup in the global account and we seized communications with the global part.

The problem is that as we're still with the global account, and we don't have access to it anymore.

If we implement the facebook login in the brazil account, when the user tries to login, as we are now on a different account (brazil), the facebook ID is different from the old account (global) and we can't find the user on our database (because the user's facebook ID is now different).

**Is there a way to prove to facebook that we were the same company as the global and keep the user id when login?**

Comment: You can only get the same app-scoped user ids, if you keep using the same app id. And if you want to match ASIDs across different apps, then the requirement for that is that those apps belong to the same business entity to begin with, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/for-business

Comment: Yeah, it looks like that would work but unfortunately we don't belong to the same business entity anymore =(